# Can't call a function a modal within a modal in angular-UI bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Using Angular Bootstrap UI I am opening a modal to allow the user to make some selections... from that modal the user can click on a help icon that would in turn open another modal.  The second modal opens and displays perfectly, but I cannot trigger any functions from the second modal.  I am trying to use ng-click for both the first and second modals.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong... when I initiated the 2nd modal I wasn't passing in scope.

```
   $scope.rptHelp = function() {
        $modalInstance2 = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'rptHelpModal.html',
            scope: $scope    //this line was missing
        });
    }
```